# Python windows path not detecting

Tags: python, windows, path, watchdog

I am using wathdog to detect new files, modified files using watchdog python module in windows operating system.

But it is unable to detect file path

my code and located at something like  L:\my_code\watch.py (in L drive )

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

    

def on_created(event):
    print(f"hey, {event.src_path} has been created!")
    

def on_deleted(event):
    print(f"Someone deleted {event.src_path}!")

def on_modified(event):
    print(f"hey, {event.src_path} has been modified")
    

def on_moved(event):
    print(f"hey, someone moved {event.src_path} to {event.dest_path}")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    patterns = ["*"]
    ignore_patterns = None
    ignore_directories = False
    case_sensitive = True
    my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)

    my_event_handler.on_created = on_created
    my_event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
    my_event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
    my_event_handler.on_moved = on_moved
    from pathlib import Path
    str_path = "\L\_REC"   
    
    path =  r"L:\_REC"
    #path = 'L:\\_REC'
    go_recursively = True
    my_observer = Observer()
    my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)

    my_observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_observer.stop()
        my_observer.join()
```

I required to detect file changes under L:\_REC directory but I am getting below error

```
& 'C:\Users\vcimalap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\vcimalap\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.5.829140558\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '57901' '--' 'l:\External\watch_service.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "l:\External\watch_service.py", line 71, in <module>
    my_observer.start()
  File "C:\Users\vcimalap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 256, in start
    emitter.start()
  File "C:\Users\vcimalap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\watchdog\utils\__init__.py", line 93, in start
    self.on_thread_start()
  File "C:\Users\vcimalap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\read_directory_changes.py", line 66, in on_thread_start 
    self._handle = get_directory_handle(self.watch.path)
  File "C:\Users\vcimalap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 316, in get_directory_handle
    return CreateFileW(path, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, WATCHDOG_FILE_SHARE_FLAGS,
  File "C:\Users\vcimalap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 112, in _errcheck_handle
    raise ctypes.WinError()
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified.
PS L:\External>
```

I am thinking defined file path is wrong, can someone help me to fix the issue

Comment: Does the path actually exist?

Comment: yes, It is under L dirve _REC folder

Comment: It's possible there's an issue with watchdog and network drives. I've just tried locally and hit the same problem, though it does seem that people use it for that. *Edit: Not true. Ironically, I spelled the directory name wrong.*

Comment: This code worked for me with a valid path on my system.